# How to use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main programatically as I want to set cucumber names as system property and also use tags via command line?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, junit4

I'm using Junit4, cucumber 7.9 and selenium 4.15 versions. In my Maven Cucumber Selenium Java project, I would like to pass cucumber tags via cli and also pass cucumber test names via system property (testrail tests with API calls). When I test, only the tags are taken into effect and names are ignored.

CLI command:

```
-ea
-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@test and (not @ignore)"
```

Testrunner class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "stepdefinitions",
        plugin = {"utils.report.CustomCucumberFormatter:", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-report.json", "pretty"},
        monochrome = true
)
public class TestRunner {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() {
        // Obtain names through API calls
        getCucumberNamesFromAPI();

        // Run Cucumber tests using io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
        runCucumberTests();
        GlobalHooks.beforeRun();

    }

    private static void getCucumberNamesFromAPI() {
          //<API logic>
            System.setProperty("cucumber.filter.name", cucumberNameOption.toString());
        }

    }

    private static void runCucumberTests() {

        String[] argv = {
                "--glue", "stepdefinitions",
                "--plugin", "utils.report.CustomCucumberFormatter:,json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-report.json,pretty",
                "--monochrome",
                "src/test/resources/features",
                "--tags", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags"),
                "--name", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.name")
        };

        io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(argv, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}
```

Even with the above code, I see all the feature files in tags selected and not the overlap of names and tags.